# Ionic tabs badge stuck at disabled color

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I based my tabs badges on the codepen: http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/knyLj

```
    <ion-tab title="Todo" icon="ion-ios-filing" href="#/tab/todo" 
             badge="data.badgeCount" badge-style="badge-assertive" 
             ng-controller="TodoTabCtrl">
        <ion-nav-view name="todo-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
```

But mine come out with the badge number style as disabled even though the tab is selected.

all of my code is almost exactly identical to the pen, except that I use templates on separate html files.

Please help.

[image]

The codepen is the original, of which I based my tabs on. But I don't get the same result.

UPDATE:
I found out that this only happen on Android. Even when I just testing on browser with 'ionic serve' and have ionicplatform=android params. I don't know how to show this on codepen, or if it's even possible

Comment: Could you clarify your problem? maybe with screenshots. I checked your codepen and it looks fine to me.

Comment: provide your code fiddle codepen or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

By default ionic add tabs-striped class to tabs (on android platform) which makes the badge opacity drop to 0.4. To override this add a line in app config

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("standard");
})
```

but I have no idea why the class was added automatically and why the drop in opacity